# Force compilation error on "0" argument (C++)

Tags: c++

Can anybody tell me if there is a way to force a compilation error when a `const wchar_t*` function argument  gets passed a 0 pointer?

As example:

```
void func(const wchar_t* a)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    ...
    func(0);  // <- this should generate a compilation error 
    ...
}
```

My intention here is not to skip any validation checks inside the function for this argument but rather prevent compilation if a function call simply makes no sense at all.

I am using Visual Studio 2019

Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

I tried to add an overload for std::nullptr_t as mentioned by @Jarod42

This generates a compilation error, but the error it produces is

"more than one instance of overloaded function matches the argument list"

although it prevents compilation, the error itself is kind of missleading and doesn't address the real problem

adding an overload with the parameter replaced by `int` type also get a missleading compilation error
"tried to acces a deleted function"

and yes, sadly none of those prevent a call with `(const wchar_t*)0` argument

so, i would say that i want to reject the `0` literal as well as the `(const wchar_t*)0`argument

Comment: Read about [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). It is quite related to your question..... For example, for any `int i;` the expression `(i*i)+1 > 0` is always true. A clever compiler could optimize `func(((i*i)+1 > 0)?nullptr:(wchar_t*)"a")` to `func(nullptr)` but a dumb compiler won't do that.

Comment: you don't add another overload but **delete** a specific overload

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: sorry i dont really understand your comment and how that would help me

Comment: @erik an explicit cast is how you tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing" so the compiler can't emit a warning or error when the code is valid. `(const wchar_t*)0` **is** a null pointer to `const wchar_t`. It's **not** a literal number 0 so it must be accepted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might add overload for [`std::nullptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t):

```
void func(std::nullptr_t) = delete;
```

Or maybe a catch all one:

```
template <typename T> void func(T) = delete;
```

Comment: `void func(int) = delete;` would have been better. This one complains about ambiguity, also forbids `func(nullptr);`, which OP may want to keep.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili:*"error when a const wchar_t* function argument gets passed a **0 pointer**?"* OP want to reject null pointer.

Comment: If that's what OP wants, your function doesn't help, as I can just `func((wchar_t*)0);`. For that reason, I think OP just wants to reject the zero literal.

Comment: thanks for the quick answers! unfortunately those answers produce really missleading compilation errors. I updated my question to take that into account

Comment: ok, the template overload variant is probably the best solution available. sadly it doesnt prevent calling `func((const wchar_t*)0)`. originally i was hoping for a compiler or language feature that i´m not aware of but probably neither of these exist. so, i will stick with this solution for now (the "real" function that will be using this is only used by myself internally so its only a help for me - that will probably do it) anyway, i will let the question marked as "unanswered" for 1 or 2 more days, maybe someone else has another idea. Thanks again!

Comment: Compilers might check types or with template, non-type parameters, but not regular parameter (value). So you might check for `template <auto p> foo()` but you no longer can pass runtime values, and C-string literals is also more complicated.